# Migrating multiple versions of a Userscript into a single version

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

The main question I have is: *What is the unique identifier that userscript managers use to decide if this script you are installing is a new version of one you already have or a completely different script?*

The situation: I had two versions of a userscript one for FF and one for Chrome on the now closed down userscripts.org, with different names. I have a user base with these installed. I have completely reworked the script, and plan on integrating them into a single script for all browsers. How can this be done while allowing my users to install over their old scripts, retaining their saved GM_Values?

Is it just the name? do I just submit the script twice with different names? Can the updateURL/downloadURL point to a different source than the installing script? That sounds like a pretty big security whole, if so. But if I could just creates two ~identical~ scripts with different names, point both to update off the main one, so I can phase out the old "My Script (FF)" script (it would just be a way to migrate Firefox users over to the main branch). Or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: Don't have time to check for updates and bug fixes but here's how it was a few releases ago:  GM keys off the combination of `name` and `namespace` to determine if a script was unique. TM only used `name` (A bug; probably fixed by now).  Yes, the up/down URL's can point to a diff location (that's even the point in one case). It's not that big of a risk.  As for the migration/consolidation, your users will take a hit to their GM_ data and will have to do some manual install/uninstall to merge.  You can update both scripts to export/import the values, before the merge, though.

Comment: Great. Thank you.

But I am hoping that as long as I keep the name and namespace the same that their browsers will consider these updates and keep the GM_data. Unless you are saying that GM_data is never kept on manual installs, even when it is for new versions of existing scripts. But that sort of leads to another question, when the `updateURL` points to a script with a different name, what happens?

Comment: If the name and namespace are the same, then the data *should* be preserved, but I haven't tested this on either engine.  If the updateURL has a different name, errors occurred (haven't checked in a long time though).  I suggest you set up some test scripts and test all of this in both GM and TM. And/or browse the GM/TM source code.  I don't have the time to do either right now.